# Join two tables according to different columns

Tags: python

I have two dataframes DB1 and DB2 in Pandas, both with a `names` column containing the names of companies. I used fuzzy string-matching with `string_grouper` package to get a table `matches` for companies present in both DB1 and DB2, according to `names` columns, which looks like:

[image]

Now I want to join DB1 and DB2 to `matches`, i.e. append their columns to matches, but only for the companies which show up in matches.

So, I want to use `matches['left_side']` as equivalent to DB1['names'] (i.e. append, to each row of `matches`, the row from DB1 where `DB1['names']` value is equivalent to the value in `matches['left_side']`) and `matches['right_side']` as equivalent to DB2['names'] in DB2. (i.e. append, to each row of `matches`, the row from DB2 where `DB2['names']` value is equivalent to the value in `matches['right_side']`)

How can I do this?

I also think it may be necessary to rename DB2['names'] since otherwise the resulting joined table would have same-named columns from DB1['names'] and DB2['names']?

Edit: happy to use SQL instead of Pandas if necessary

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not just select the data from the db already joined like this? "Select * from DB1 Left Join DB2 on name = name"

Comment: Because I'm looking for approximate matches not exact ones, hence use of ```string_grouper``` in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df_db1 = ...
df_db2 = ...
df_matches = ...

# merge matches with db1 and specify the columns you want to use as key
df_matches = df_matches.reset_index().merge(df_db1, left_on=['left_side'], right_on=['names'], how="left", suffixes=["matches_", "db1_"]).set_index("index")
# merge matches (already matched with db1) again with db2 and specify the new columns you want to use as key
df_matches = df_matches.reset_index().merge(df_db2, left_on=['right_side'], right_on=['names'], how="left", suffixes=["matches_", "db2_"]).set_index("index")
```

The .`reset_index()` ... `.set_index("index")` part is to keep the initial index of df_matches otherwise they would be resettet.

Also you do not have to rename the columns beforhand because you can use the `suffixes` parameter like this: `suffixes=["matches_", "db1_"]` which will automatically rename the columns if case there are 2 columns with the same name.

Also keep in mind that if either df_db1 or df_db2 has `duplicates` for a key, you will have both in the new df_matches as well. If you don't want that you have to do duplicate management before that.

Comment: thanks! will test it out in a minute. Should the second ```suffixes``` read ```suffixes=["matches_", "db2_"]```?